# Fibre channel multipath

Tags: fibre-channel, multipath

I have a server with two FC adapters connected to Sun 6140 (IBM DS4700) array. One adapter (1) is connected to Cisco MDS switch and that switch connected to both array controllers. Second adapter (2) is connected directly to one of the array controllers.

Sun 6140 is declared as multipath-ready and I have multipathd working. But multipath -ll show me that I have three paths to my disks, but only 2 paths on 1 adapter is working at the moment, third one (direct) is in ghost state. My best guess is that array accept multipath from one point only and my question is what is the parameter it rely on?

Is it WWNN and if yes how may I change WWNN? Or maybe there is something else I can do so the array think it is dealing with one machine on all 3 links?